# osx: ld return codes

Tags: macos, ld, exit-code

I am trying to link a few static libraries to create the final executable for iOS using a build script. My problem is that `ld`always exits with code 136. My question is: how can I find out what code 136 means? `man ld` does not mention any return codes at all. I found two lists of system error codes but none for ld:
[System error codes from 0 to -261](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1618), [System error codes from 1 to 32767](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2088?viewlocale=en_US)

Alternatively, how can I get `ld` to tell me the problem. I have tried all the options for logging but none of them get it to print anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, exit codes greater than 127 mean that a signal terminated your program. The signal number is the exit code - 128. In your case,the signal with the number 8 is SIGFPE. Seems like a floating point exception was the cause of the abort.

Comment: Any idea why a linker could get a floating point exception? How can I find out what is causing the problem?